# `TypeError: perspectiveMatrix() got an unexpected keyword argument 'inverse'` in OpenGLContext callback

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl

I am starting to learn OpenGL and I tried to run the program in this [tutorial](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/context/tutorials/shader_1.xhtml). This is the code I have got together from that page. I had to lower the GLSL version in the shaders to get it to run at all on my laptop (they were 330).

```
from OpenGLContext import testingcontext
BaseContext = testingcontext.getInteractive()

from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.arrays import vbo
from OpenGLContext.arrays import *
from OpenGL.GL import shaders

class TestContext( BaseContext ):
    """Creates a simple vertex shader..."""

    def OnInit(self):

        VERTEX_SHADER = shaders.compileShader("""
            #version 130
            void main() {
                gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
            }
            """, GL_VERTEX_SHADER)

        FRAGMENT_SHADER = shaders.compileShader("""
            #version 130
            void main() {
                 gl_FragColor = vec4(0, 1, 0, 1);
            }""", GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)

        self.shader = shaders.compileProgram(VERTEX_SHADER, FRAGMENT_SHADER)

        self.vbo = vbo.VBO(
            array( [
                [  0, 1, 0 ],
                [ -1,-1, 0 ],
                [  1,-1, 0 ],
                [  2,-1, 0 ],
                [  4,-1, 0 ],
                [  4, 1, 0 ],
                [  2,-1, 0 ],
                [  4, 1, 0 ],
                [  2, 1, 0 ],
            ],'f')
        )

    def render(self, mode):
        shaders.glUseProgram(self.shader)

        try:
            self.vbo.bind()
            try:
                glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
                glVertexPointerf(self.vbo)

                glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 9)
            finally:
                self.vbo.unbind()
                glDisableClientState(GL_VERTERX_ARRAY)
        finally:
            shaders.glUseProgram(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestContext.ContextMainLoop()
```

This is the error I am getting if I run the program. The error repeats if I move my mouse on top of the small window that appears, so the app is alive, but not really functional. The window shows what was behind it when the app started, so no real picture.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "_ctypes/callbacks.c", line 314, in 'calling callback function'
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenGLContext/events/glutevents.py", line 33, in glutOnMouseMove
    self.triggerPick()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenGLContext/context.py", line 590, in triggerPick
    self.OnDraw()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenGLContext/context.py", line 515, in OnDraw
    visibleChange = self.renderPasses( self )
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenGLContext/passes/renderpass.py", line 866, in __call__
    return FLAT( context )
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenGLContext/passes/flatcompat.py", line 298, in __call__
    self.setViewPlatform( vp )
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenGLContext/passes/flatcompat.py", line 334, in setViewPlatform
    self.projection = vp.viewMatrix().astype('f')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenGLContext/move/viewplatform.py", line 158, in viewMatrix
    inverse=inverse,
  File "tmatrixaccel.pyx", line 55, in vrml_accelerate.tmatrixaccel.perspectiveMatrix (src/tmatrixaccel.c:1990)
TypeError: perspectiveMatrix() got an unexpected keyword argument 'inverse'
```

I am a complete noob when it comes to OpenGL, so I really don't know where to start looking for a problem, as it is not even directly from my code, but by some callback. Do I have somehow incompatible packages?

My versions:

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Oct  8 2013, 12:19:40) 
[GCC 4.8.1 20130603 (Red Hat 4.8.1-1)] on linux2

PyOpenGL                  - Standard OpenGL bindings for Python
  INSTALLED: 3.1.0a3 (latest)

OpenGLContext             - Demonstration and testing contexts for PyOpenGL/OpenGL-ctypes
  INSTALLED: 2.2.0a3 (latest)

PyOpenGL-accelerate       - Acceleration code for PyOpenGL
  INSTALLED: 3.1.0a3 (latest)

OpenGLContext-full        - Installs all of OpenGLContext with optional dependencies
  INSTALLED: 2.1.0a9 (latest)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is a bug in one of the libraries used and not in your code. Essentially Python tells you, that the way `perspectiveMatrix` is invoked liked, doesn't match the actual signature of the function.

You need to file a bug report with the creators of the libraries you use.

Comment: That's what I thought, but wanted to verify